# Tag rename request: [sao-hollow-fragment] -> [sword-art-online-hollow-fragment]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I want to request the rename of the tag [sao-hollow-fragment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sao-hollow-fragment) to [sword-art-online-hollow-fragment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sword-art-online-hollow-fragment) (and probably making the old one a synonym).

The reason is simple: to keep consistency with other tags like [sword-art-online-fatal-bullet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sword-art-online-fatal-bullet) and [sword-art-online-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sword-art-online-series).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> updating post history, 4 rows affected (pipe delimited)
>   updating posts, 4 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
>   Target tag 'sword-art-online-hollow-fragment' doesn't exist, renaming to 'sao-hollow-fragment'
>   rename result: 1 rows affected
>   tag remapping of [sword-art-online-hollow-fragment] and [sao-hollow-fragment] complete!
>   remapping 0 synonyms
>   1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
>   0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
>   Tag Synonym sao-hollow-fragment -> sword-art-online-hollow-fragment was approved!

I also changed [sao-lost-song](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sao-lost-song) to [sword-art-online-lost-song](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sword-art-online-lost-song).